# Trigger email from grails controller

Tags: email, grails, plugins, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have written a groovy controller that sends email:

```
package com.test

class LibraryController {
    def mailService
    def sendEmail() {
        mailService.sendMail{
            to "test@gmail.com"
            from "receive@gmail.com"
            subject "Testing email system"
            body "Hi Checking the service"
        }
        render "test"
    }
}
```

And when I take the url -> http://server_name:8080/library/sendEmail , it will send email. 
I tried to add this as command in cron(in linux server) like:

```
crontab -e
*/5 * * * * http://server_name:8080/library/sendEmail
```

But it didn't send the email by running this in every 5 minute.

Please help!

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you have tried and what didn't work about what you have tried. Using a general term like `cron job` isn't going to help. Do you want to call it from a *nix cron job? Do you want to set it on a schedule/timer within your Grails application? Your question doesn't include a lot of information about what you need and what you have tried.

Comment: edited the question - I want to call it from  *nix cron job - since we have another scheduler to call it, I can't use quartz

Comment: I think your cron expression should be `*/5` for every 5 minutes... If that isn't it, what happens other than an email isn't set? Is there an exception from Grails? Is there a hit in the access log?

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions and I think , cron didn't even call the method sendEmail() in controller.

Answer (score 4):

Put `curl` before url in your cron expression.
Like that:

`*/5 * * * * curl http://server_name:8080/library/sendEmail`

`curl` or `wget` will call your url and send email.

But, if I could suggest another way to schedule tasks in your grails app. I recomend [Quartz-Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/quartz) or `ScheduledExecutorService`, that last one is native from java.